# coderedirect.com is scraping stackoverflow.com and listed above on Google

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure what can be done about this,
but I've noticed lately that stackoverflow.com is being scraped by coderedirect.com
and their horrible looking, ad-laden page is the top listing on Googles search results.

As an example my latest search result is ["Lines 43-44 of Profile.java are:"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Lines%2043-44%20of%20Profile.java%20are%3A%22)

Comment: I remember coming across this site and I had reported it in the [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact?referrer=https%3a%2f%2fmeta.stackoverflow.com%2f) page. You could too if you wish.

Comment: @SurajRao note that if it's only scraping the site without proper attribution, SE is not interested in handling the report anymore.

Comment: @AndrewT. Too bad.. for example [This link](https://coderedirect.com/questions/383981/missing-user-class-creating-entity-relationship-to-user-entity-in-microservice) is not only scraping the question but seems to have grabbed answers from _different questions in SO_. That is quite a bit of misinfo

Comment: Absolutely nothing; there's scraper sites with 0 attribution that rank _higher_ than Stack Overflow (I've literally seen a flag where someone thought an answer was plagiarized from a scraper site with 0 attribution), and the company still doesn't care anymore.

Comment: You can report it to Google: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/spamreportform